# Building a function to identify elements in rows of dataframe in R and replace them after a comparison

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little problem in R. I have a dataframe in R with `code` variable and five variables. It looks like this (I add `dput()` version at the end
):

```
   Code   C1   C2   C3   C4 C5
1 abc1    A    A    A    A  A
2 bbb1    B Mark    C    C  C
3  cc2    C    C Mark    D  D
4 ccc3    D Mark    E Mark  E
5 ddd1    A Mark    B    B  B
6 ddd1 Mark Mark    B    B  B
```

My problem is with rows, `code` is a variable only for reference. The thing I want to solve is the next. In each row is possible to have the string `Mark`. When `Mark` is found at any row, then I have to make a comparison, first between `Mark` and the element that is located before the position of `Mark`, and second between `Mark` and the element that is located after the position of `Mark`. In other words when I find `Mark` I have to compare this with the element that is in the position of `Mark` plus 1 and with the element that is in the position of `Mark` less 1. In both comparison I have to evaluate if `Mark` is different to the element in position of `Mark` less one and if `Mark` is different to the element in position of `Mark` plus one. If `Mark` is different to both elements then I have to replace `Mark` with the same element in position `Mark` plus one. For example in row number two I had `B`, `Mark` and `C`. The function I tried to write should make this: First identify if `Mark` is in the row, second it will compare `Mark` with the element in position `Mark`-1, in this case `B`, third it will compare `Mark` with the element in position `Mark`+1 in this case `C`. In first comparison `Mark` is different to `B` and in the second `Mark` is differente to `C`. This case satisfies both comparisons, the `Mark` will be replaced by the element in the position `Mark`+1, in the example would be `C`. I made a function but I don't know what is wrong. My dataframes is `test`. The function is:

```
test[-1] <- t(apply(
  test[-1],
  1,
  function(x) {
    if(x=="Mark" & x!=x[which(x)-1] & x!=x[which(x)+1]) {
      x=x[which(x)+1]
    } else
      x
  }
))
```

When I apply this over `test` I got this error:

```
Error in which(x) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

I tried to fix the logic inside the function but it doesn't work. I know `which()` detect position but here give me error. I would like to get something like this:

```
   Code   C1   C2 C3 C4 C5
1 abc1    A    A  A  A  A
2 bbb1    B    C  C  C  C
3  cc2    C    C  D  D  D
4 ccc3    D    E  E  E  E
5 ddd1    A    B  B  B  B
6 ddd1 Mark Mark  B  B  B
```

I would like to identify what is wrong in the function. The `dput` version of `test` is the next:

```
structure(list(Code = c("abc1", "bbb1", "cc2", "ccc3", "ddd1", 
"ddd1"), C1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "Mark"), C2 = c("A", 
"Mark", "C", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark"), C3 = c("A", "C", "Mark", 
"E", "B", "B"), C4 = c("A", "C", "D", "Mark", "B", "B"), C5 = c("A", 
"C", "D", "E", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Code", "C1", "C2", "C3", 
"C4", "C5"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `which` is not being passed a logical expression resulting in `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You need something like: `which(x=="Mark")-1` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but it seems like this might do the trick for you. I usually steer clear of `which` because it makes things a bit more confusing than it has to be.  We can solve this problem simply by using the position numbers of the data, when converted into matrix form and from factor to character variables.

```
## get the data
> dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Code   C1   C2   C3   C4 C5
  1 abc1    A    A    A    A  A
  2 bbb1    B Mark    C    C  C
  3  cc2    C    C Mark    D  D
  4 ccc3    D Mark    E Mark  E
  5 ddd1    A Mark    B    B  B
  6 ddd1 Mark Mark    B    B  B", row.names = 1)

## manipulate using the position numbers
> dat <-  sapply(dat, as.character)
> nr <- nrow(dat)
> gg <- grep("Mark", dat)
> dat[gg] <- sapply(seq(dat[gg]), function(i){
      ifelse(dat[gg+nr][i] > dat[gg-nr][i], dat[gg+nr][i], dat[gg-nr][i])
  })
> as.data.frame(dat)
##   Code   C1   C2 C3 C4 C5
## 1 abc1    A    A  A  A  A
## 2 bbb1    B    C  C  C  C
## 3  cc2    C    C  D  D  D
## 4 ccc3    D    E  E  E  E
## 5 ddd1    A    B  B  B  B
## 6 ddd1 Mark Mark  B  B  B
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the column previous to C1 is, or after C5, so it's ambiguous how we should deal with `Mark`s in those columns, but assuming you're happy in those cases if the one neighbour is the same, then:

```
cols <- sprintf("C%d",1:5)
colsLeft <- c(cols[-1], cols[length(cols)])
colsRight <- c(cols[1], cols[-length(cols)])
comp <- df[cols]=="Mark" & df[colsRight]!="Mark" & df[colsLeft]!="Mark"
df[cols][comp] <- df[colsLeft][comp]
```

The idea being to set up two 'shifts' of the data frame, one to the right, one to the left.  Comp then gets set when the original is Mark, but neither of the shifted versions are.  Then set these cells of df to be the corresponding cells of the left-shifted one.